# Title of a book about a mysterious light in the sky from the late 90s?

Tags: story-identification, novel, science, religion

I vaguely remember a book and it has been driving me crazy for years. It had these things:

- A mysterious light in the sky (maybe healing people)
- Religious overtones/themes (not a religious book to my knowledge)
- A male and a female lead (I think one was a scientist)
- Took place in modern day
- Came out in '99 or '00. I remember a reference to World Trade Center attacks on 9/11, but found it odd that the copyright was before it.
- I think the cover had a bright light or a star on it.

Comment: To some extend it sounds like VALIS.

Comment: If it was VALIS, I'm sure the OP would have remembered the name of the protagonist.

Comment: It was more grounded than Valis. Also, I'd know if it were a PKD book. And yes, I'd remember the main characters name.

Comment: It could be a reference to the earlier attack on the WTC in 1993; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_World_Trade_Center_bombing

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the novel *Blue Light* by Walter Mosley from 1998?

[Wiki Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Light_%28novel%29)

> In 1965, a mysterious beam of blue light came down from space and overlooked Northern California. This light had extraterrestrial powers that caused whomever the beam touched to die, go mad, or acquire a special unique power. This power is defined as full actualization of humankind, with strengths, understandings and communication abilities that exceed our normal capabilities. The people touched by the light in the novel were soon referred to as "Blues" and were segregated from society because of their new and improved super human powers. Soon after this discovery, they came together to try and find their purpose in the universe. As they look for their calling in life, an evil force, the "Gray Man", emerges, setting the stage for a battle later on in the novel between good and evil.

Comment: If so, there's another story ID question about the same book here which might help the OP to remember more as well: [Novel about energy beams from space giving people powers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162022/novel-about-energy-beams-from-space-giving-people-powers)