# Novel about energy beams from space giving people powers

Tags: story-identification, novel

Not sure when exactly I read this, may have been in the 90s or early 00s.

The novel is set in north America I think. Some kind of energy beams or rays from space rain down on Earth. Where they happen to hit a human, that person gains some kind of power. From what I remember the powers were not superhero-like, they may have been related to whatever the person was doing at the moment of being struck. There was a woman who was hit whilst.. erm, "in flagrante delicto" and gained a seductive power over men. There was an antagonist who was an old man that dies just as he is struck by the energy, he becomes a kind of undead and starts killing off others who have gained powers (including a scene where he kills a messiah-like character who is speaking to a crowd).

I can't remember if the book explained the origin of the space energy, I think the climax involved the remaining people with abilities facing off with undead guy in a forested area.

Comment: Hmm. Some of the elements of this story remind me of Sanderson's *The Reckoners*, but the R-rated elements of the story definitely were *not* present in the YA trilogy.

Comment: @Shoket - there's plenty of stories with these elements - *Rising Stars* was the first to pop in my head, but that's a comic, not a novel.  The character descriptions are the key bit.

Answer (score 3):

Found it - I suddenly remembered the word "blue" being significant, which lead me to "Blue Light" by Walter Mosley.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Light_(novel)